# Problem during installation of opencart

Tags: 14.04

sir i am having a problem during installaton of opencart on my ubuntu pc.
my cURL and mcrypt is in off position while it required in on position.

Answer (score 0):

Run `apt-get install php5-curl curl php5-mcrypt` and then install opencart again.